# PROLOG code to find cheapest combination of all possible combinations

Tags: configuration, prolog, combinations, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

Complete newbie in PROLOG here. I am provided with a list of parts to implement a hypothetical computational system:

```
%partName(name, type, number, required_types, size, price)
part(a-1, a, 1, 2*b, 0.5, 60 )
part(a-2, a, 2, 3*b, 1.0, 25 )
part(b-1, b, 1, 2*c, 0.5, 25 )
part(b-2, b, 2, -, 1, 45 )
part(c-1, c, 1, -, 0.5, 5 )
part(c-2, c, 2, -, 0.5, 10 )
part(d-1, d, 1, 1*b && 2*c, 0.5, 45 )
part(d-2, d, 2, 1*c-1, 0.5, 25 )
```

For example: part a-1, of type a and number 1, needs two (2) b-type parts to function (either two b-1s or two b-2s of one of each), and then b-1 requires another two (2) c-type parts to function, etc. Parts also include a size (half size is 0.5, full size is 1) and a price.

(NOTE: parts with "-" as needed type work on their own, part d-1 requires one b-type AND two c types, and d-2 requires one c-1 in particular rather than generally a c type.)

The input is to be a setup of part types, like {a, b}, {c, d}, {a, b, d} etc.
The output is to be the cheapest possible configuration/combination of them in terms of space and money.
Remember: for example, in {a, b}, "a" can either be a-1 or a-2 (same with b) and each part needs the parts listed above in order to function and so on, so I presume it all works in a tree like, somewhat "recursive" manner.

I guess I first have to find all possible combinations/configurations and then somehow find the cheapest/most compact.

Can anyone provide a working solution or basic insight on how to set up the problem?
Please be a lifesaver.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far to solve the problem and ask specific questions about that.

Comment: I don't think you can you `&&` like that in a term, use a list of requirements instead, also the first argument is redundant. Lastly it is not clear exactly what input and output is expected e.g. what is`{a,b},{c,d},{a,b,d}' ? is it meant to be one query or three? Why do these not have a number?

Comment: `1*b && 2*c` in this context is a syntax error in Prolog since `&&` isn't recognized as an operator. You could define it as one using [`op/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=op/3) if you wish to define it, or use a valid operator symbol. Once you've cleared up your syntax issues, you can use unification to extract information. For example, `part(d-1, d, 1, Exp, 0.5, 45 ).` would yield `Exp = 1*b && 2*c.`. And you can write a predicate to break down `Exp` by unifying it with acceptable forms: `Exp = X && Y` would yield `X = 1*b` and `Y = 2*c`, assuming you've defined `&&`.

Comment: This is a combinatorial optimization problem, which is well researched and solvers exist for this kind of thing, such as CPLEX. I would look to using an interface to one of these solvers if this is a work-thing. If this is a learning exercise, look for the simplex and tableau methods for combinatorial optimization. If you've not studied this before, expect to put as much into learning it as your Prolog.